# How to extract CA Certificate from .pfx file and add it to a trust store file

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore

I have a `.pfx` file that has multiple certificates, one of them is the signing CA certificate of a server certificate assigned to the IBM i Remote Command Server in DCM.

I managed to use `openssl` and `certutil` to display the content of such a certificate, as follows:

```
openssl x509 -passin pass:<password> -text -noout -in filename.pfx
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -passin pass:<password> -info -nokeys
certutil -v -dump DEVP20.pfx
```

All the above are working fine and displaying content, but the problem is that I don't know how to analyze such output.

Also, the `keytool` is reporting that there are no entries in the keystone:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore filename.pfx
Enter keystore password: <entery-password>
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

All I want is to create a new trust store or use an existing trust store such as `jssecacerts` to add the signing CA Certificate to the trust store.

Note that in the output of the different commands above I see multiple certificates. I am not sure if they are part of the chain or related, and by checking the alias or friendly name, I can tell which one I want.

The objective is to be able to use the class `SecureAS400` from IBM Toolbox for Java to open a secure connection to the IBM i and invoke a command. So we have to load the trust store with the JVM.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to extract the CA certificate from the .pfx file using openssl:
`openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -passin pass:<password> -info -nokeys > filename.pem`.
Double check that extraction worked:
`openssl x509 -in test.pem -noout -text`

Then either create new JKS using the key tool:
`keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore test.jks -storepass choose-password -file test.pem -alias CANAME`

Or you can import the certificate into the existing trust store:
`keytool -import -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -file test.pem -alias CANAME -storetype JKS`

Usually you would use openssl to interact with most certificate file formats and `keytool` with java key stores only (JKS)

==============.
**Update**
PKCS12 is an archive file format for storing private keys and X.509 certificates with filename extensions `.p12` or `.pfx`
To be able to work with `.pfx` files you would use `openssl pkcs12` command.  I am guessing `x509` command returns first certificate it finds.
[PKCS12 wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)

`keytool` Manages a keystore (database) of cryptographic keys, X.509 certificate chains, and trusted certificates.
I think it only works with java keystores `.jks` or `.bcfks` (Bouncy Castle FIPS keyStore) etc..
I think you might actually be able to import certificates directly from `.pfx` file to a java keystore using `keytool`.

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mypfxfile.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS`

That could also import the private key if it's in the `.pfx` file but I am not sure.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why with 'openssl pkcs12` I see 3 certificates in the output, but with `openssl x509` for the same pfx file, I see only one certificate?

Comment: Yes, it worked, but I  don't understand what I am doing. Can you please clarify? Why the first command was `openssl pkcs12` instead of `openssl x509`? Where did the other 2 certificates go? And, why the `keytool` didn't work initially in my case? I am a bit lost here.

Comment: @tarekahf Updated the answer.

Comment: Java crypto including `keytool` has supported PKCS12 _for keystore_ (privatekey _plus_ own cert/chain) since it began, but _for truststore_ (CA or other party bare cert) only since Java 8 in 2013 **using a special bag-attribute** that other software doesn't. It also supports JKS and other formats depending on the providers in the JVM, which OP didn't identity. @tarekhf: see my bold for why Java doesn't find trusted-certs in your PFX/PKCS12, so yes you must use `openssl pkcs12` to get cert(s) (as PEM) and `keytool -importcert` to a keystore format supported by your JVM.

Comment: ... (Yan+) also note that if you have multiple certs in the PKCS12, `openssl pkcs12` outputs all of them, but `keytool -importcert` _for trustedcert_ only works on one at a time. You must either select the correct _one_ from PKCS12 output, or split it apart and do each desired/needed cert separately. (OTOH when importing a CA reply _to and for a privatekey entry_ it can read a whole chain.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for further clarification.  Going between formats especially dealing with keytool usually a bit of a pain :)

Comment: Thank you all... What really amazes me is that one could figure out how to move in such a maze and find the exit. I will add an answer soon to update you on what happened.

Comment: I get into this maze at least once a year when certificates about to expire :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yan and @dave_thompson_085 for the answer and info provided.

Finally, we found out that the provided PFX file wasn't necessary. There was a `.cer` file that had the certificate chain to be trusted. I used this new `.cer` file and picked one `cacerts` from the JRE security library, copied it, changed its name, and added the `.cer` file to the copy of the `cacerts` file. The justification is that we may need to trust some of the certificates that are shipped with JRE and this will save some time.

I used a desktop tool from "IBM i Client Access Solutions" called "Key Management" to import the `cer` file to the copy of the `cacerts` file. Now, I have a new `jks` file to be used for the Java program that will use the class `SecureAS400` to open a secured RPC Connection to IBM i.

---

**Some extra stuff for verification and clarification:**

I used the extracted `pem` file from the provided `pfx` file as mentioned by @Yan... I imported the `pem` file using `keytool import` to a copy of the cacerts file so now I have, say,  `cacerts_a.jks`.

I understood that this `pfx` file has the root CA as well as the private key of the server certificate, and looks like there is a certificate in the middle so it has a total of 3 certificates.

Then, I understood that ... no... I have to use a new `cer` file with the trust chain. I used this new `pem` file and imported it to a copy of the `cacerts` file and now I have, say, `cacerts_b.jks`.

I tried to compare the output of the following two commands:

```
>keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts_a.jks -storepass changeit | clip
>keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts_b.jks -storepass changeit | clip
```

I compared the output of the above two commands and found that there are significant differences between the `pem/cer` extracted from the `pfx` file and the given `cer` file with the trust chain. It seems to me that we shouldn't get the trust chain for the `pfx` file that is meant to have the server certificate.